# How do I make a batch file launch a certain part of another batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a .bat game and I'm putting in save files but I'm not sure how to, what I want it to do basically is run a batch file, "Warrior", then go to a certain part of the code-:Fight_1. I've looked everywhere but can't find anything. I don't need all the code, I know how to start batch files and that and I know the call command I just don't know how to call a certain part of a batch file.
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please avoid those questions by learning the basics first. Try `goto :Fight_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, very easy (You should learn basic batch first) but here's the quick solution:

#### Call.bat

```
Warrior.bat Fight_1
```

#### Warrior.bat

```
Rem start of Warrior File

if "%1" neq "" ( goto %1)

:: Code Here

:Fight_1

:: Fight code here

Exit
```

That will work as long as you call tags that exist in the file, otherwise you'll get an error message and the program will fail.

Mona

Comment: Thanks :) and yeah I know a fair bit of bat